# JPanel resizes unexpectedly

Tags: java, swing

I am facing issues with how a JPanel is resizing itself, based on the number of components it has. The context is summarized here:

1. There is a container panel, that has GridBagLayout, with 2 columns and 1 row. The weights for the columns are 0.0 and 1.0 respectively, whereas that for the row is 1.0 (the second column should take all the extra area of the parent). The fill criteria for both components is "BOTH".
2. As the 2nd component in the row, a JScrollPane holding a content panel is added. This panel can have varying number of children. However, it should only grow horizontally, and not vertically (the children get added as a new column each, within the 2nd panel).
3. However, when the size of the child panel, increases beyond the size of the parent, it takes up an additional **5 pixels** of space **vertically**, which should not be happening. The screenshot of the two cases are below:

[image]

and
[image]

The size of the panel containing the Bar Graphs is **310** in the first case, whereas it is **315** in the second case. This, when the only thing that changes in the two cases is the **number of bars**, which are added as separate columns to the content panel.

Can anyone point to me how to debug this problem? Where should I look? In my view, the extra vertical space that the panel takes is unwarranted, but I do not get the reason for it.

The relevant part of the code is below:

```
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0};
        setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        YAxis yAxis = new YAxis(start, end);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_yAxis = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_yAxis.gridx = 0;
        gbc_yAxis.gridy = 0;
        gbc_yAxis.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(yAxis, gbc_yAxis);
        JPanel chartsContainer = new JPanel() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
    //              System.out.println(getSize());
            }
        };
        chartsContainer.setOpaque(false);
        GridBagLayout gbl_chartsContainer = new GridBagLayout();
        int[] colWidths = new int[statsToDisplay.size() + 1];
        Arrays.fill(colWidths, 25);
        colWidths[colWidths.length-1] = 0;
        gbl_chartsContainer.columnWidths = colWidths;
        double[] colWeights = new double[statsToDisplay.size()+1];
        Arrays.fill(colWeights, 0);
        colWeights[colWeights.length-1] = 1.0;
        gbl_chartsContainer.rowHeights = new int[] {50};
        gbl_chartsContainer.columnWeights = colWeights;
        gbl_chartsContainer.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0};
        chartsContainer.setLayout(gbl_chartsContainer);

            /* Code to fill chartsContainer goes here */

        JScrollPane chartScrollPane = new JScrollPane(chartsContainer);
        chartScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        chartScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_chartScrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_chartScrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_chartScrollPane.gridx = 1;
        gbc_chartScrollPane.gridy = 0;
        add(chartScrollPane, gbc_chartScrollPane);
```

Comment: It looks like its accounting for the horizontalbar height when it becomes enabled, try to fix it in the layout

Comment: I tried adding the Panel directly to the container, forgoing the scroll pane. Same result - 5 added pixels when the number of children are more.

Comment: Setting the panel to 315 increases to 320?

Comment: No. I am not providing any heights myself. It is supposed to be done on the fly by the LayoutManager (based on how much space the parent panel has been allocated). 315 and 320 are sample values. For everything else being constant, the panel takes 315 as height, when the number of children are less, and 320, when the number of children are more.

Comment: Tried? scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

Comment: And also for vertical, cause note that your picture add the vertical one when content overflow

Comment: Yes. Tried. Same result. In fact I totally removed the scroll pane, and added the panel directly to the container. Same result.

Comment: Vertical I am already setting to NEVER.

Comment: For now, I've just set the size of the container to a fixed value - which is not good, but it solves the problem for now. But I am interested in knowing if anyone else faced anything similar to this.